# Loading data from Hadoop Cascading Source into MySQL Sink

Tags: mysql, hadoop, cascading

I'm trying to integrate writing data in from a Cascading source into MySQL so I wonder if there's an easy sink available to take the tab delimited data that's coming from the source and just doing a couple SQL statements to update a table.

I'm new to Cascading so I'd love any help here!

Comment: I don't have any code yet outside of a traditional cascading job. I'm looking for a connector to MySQL that can serve as the sink pipe to the job.

Answer (score 1):

There's a project on Github, which is a set of Cascading (version 2.2 and above) Taps and Schemes which interact with RDBMS systems via JDBC. Hope it helps https://github.com/Cascading/cascading-jdbc.